# How to make an On/Off Function

Tags: actionscript-3, events, click, mouseevent, flashdevelop

When I click in the stage, anywhere, it calls a function that will change one variables value. How do I make it so when I click again it changes back to original value?

```
public function Example() {
(...)
Modifier = 1;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Happening);
}

public function Happening(event:Event) {
Modifier = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about keeping a seperate boolean variable?

```
var clicked:Boolean = false;
var Modifier:int = 1;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Happening);

public function Happening(e:MouseEvent):void{
   if(clicked){
     //return to default
     Modifier = 1;
     clicked = false;
   }else{
     Modifier = 4;
     clicked = true;
   }
}
```

or even simpler

```
if(Modifier==4){
   Modifier=1;
}else{
   Modifier=4;
}
```

or in one line

```
Modifier = (Modifier==4) ? 1 : 4;
```

Comment: Yeah it was dumb of me not thinking of this (On/Off = True/False). Even though I'm just learning flash I do know what booleans are and could've got to that solution! :P Thank you anyways

Comment: sometimes you just need a little nudge in the right direction ;) no problem, glad to be able to help